# variables lose their labels after mutate() function is applied in R

Tags: r, dplyr, label, mutation, hmisc

so assume some of my df columns have labels.

```
library(Hmisc)
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(0,1,2), b = c(0,1,2), d = c(0,1,2), e = c(0,1,2),
                  f= c("m","f","o"), output = c(0,1,2))
var_labs <- c(a = "aaa",
              b = "bbb",
              #d = "ddd",
              #e = "eee",
              f = "fff",
              output = "ooo")
label(df1) <- as.list(var_labs[match(names(df1), names(var_labs))])
```

[image]

When I apply `mutate()` functions on any column, that column loses its label.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
   mutate_if(is.character,
             .funs = as.factor)
```

[image]

Is there a way to keep the labels after mutating?

Comment: You define `df1` but then work on `df`, is that a typo or are you accidentally working on a previously-defined dataset?

Comment: Yes a typo. Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first save the labels of `df1` and after that assign again the labels to `match`ing columns to `df2` like this:

```
labs <- Hmisc::label(df1)
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate_if(is.character,
            .funs = as.factor)

label(df2) <- as.list(labs[match(names(df2), names(labs))])
str(df2)
```

Output:

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ a     : 'labelled' num  0 1 2
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "aaa"
 $ b     : 'labelled' num  0 1 2
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "bbb"
 $ d     : 'labelled' num  0 1 2
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr NA
 $ e     : 'labelled' num  0 1 2
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr NA
 $ f     : Factor w/ 3 levels "f","m","o": 2 1 3
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "fff"
 $ output: 'labelled' num  0 1 2
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "ooo"
```

`view(df2)`:

[image]

Comment: With `var_label` from `labelled` package we could do it more direct: `labs <- df1 %>% var_label(.)` then do some label attribute destroying action like using across etc.. finally do just `var_label(df1) <- labs`. :-)

Comment: Hi @TarJae, Thanks for your suggestion! That is also a really smart way!

Answer (score 3):

The `Hmisc` labels functions annotate the individual vectors in the data.frame, not the data.frame itself. So the problem is that the `as.factor()` function stips off the label from the column. You could add a version that preserves the labels

```
as.factor.labelled <- function(x) {
  r <- as.factor(as.character(x))
  label(r)<-label(x)
  r
}
```

Then the mutate should keep those labels because this new version of `as.factor` will keep the labels.